# Match against query not returning correct results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tags t WHERE 
MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 1') OR 
MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 2') OR 
MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 3') OR 
MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 4') OR 
MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 5') AND 
(t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 1' AND t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 2' AND 
 t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 3' AND t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 4' AND 
 t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 5')
```

The above query still returns string 1, string 3, and string 4. Is my algorithm incorrect? I only want to find rows that have similar tag names, but exclude the ones were checking against.

Comment: Can you show some sample data? Maybe an sqlfiddle?

Comment: I doubt the parentheses are set up the way you really want them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to surround the ORs with (), but the ANDs don't need that:

```
SELECT * FROM tags t WHERE 
(MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 1') OR 
MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 2') OR 
MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 3') OR 
MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 4') OR 
MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST ('string 5')) AND 
t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 1' AND t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 2' AND 
 t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 3' AND t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 4' AND 
 t.tag NOT LIKE 'string 5'
```

Take a look on "operator precedence":

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

AND is normally resolved before OR, but in your case, the all the ORs have to be resolved before as a group, so we add () to force them to be resolved before the ANDs.

Another possible issue: `NOT LIKE 'string 1'` is the same as `<> 'string 1'`. If you want to remove tags which DO NOT CONTAIN 'string 1', you should use `NOT LIKE '%string 1%'`.